# regex match 2 cases

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a problem finding the correct match for all the cases.
I want to catch something string( here in my example ##xyx##) which is in the quotes for example,
if i have something like

Case 1)

```
               <picture href="hello" ##xyz##>##xyz##</picture>
```

the output should be no match found as none of them are in quotes.

if i have a different case something like

case 2)

```
            <picture href="##xyz##" dbhdfbhg="dbfdhfbhgbt fgkg ##xyz## hdjvffhgfhd">
```

i want to match both the cases which have ##xyz## as both of them are in quotes

case 3)

```
              <picture href="##xyz##">
                    ##xyz##
                     </picture>
```

the regular expression should only catch the  teh first one but not the second one ..

i have tried something like   (")([^"].*)?(##xyz##)([^"].*)?(")
which gets the wrong output.
in the case 3 its catching the second one even though i use multiline option in  regex. can some one help?
              I am using C# for coding

Comment: can you post the code where you execute the regex?  It seems to work fine for me in FireFox's Regular Expression Tester add-on, using your case 3 example.  It may be a problem encoding the regex into a c# string (such as dropping a quotation mark).

Comment: how about `(")([^"]*)(##xyz##)([^"]*)(")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the following LINQPad snippet. The regular expression uses a lookahead `(?=` to find a matching quote and then tries to match *##xyz##* within that text segment:

```
var text = "<picture href=\"##xyz##\" dbhdfbhg=\"dbfdhfbhgbt fgkg ##xyz## hdjvffhgfhd\">";
var text1 = @"<picture href=""##xyz##"">
                    ##xyz##
                    </picture>";

var regex = new Regex("\"(?=[^\"]+)[^#]*##xyz##[^\"]*\"");

var matches = regex.Matches(text);
var matches1 = regex.Matches(text1);
matches.Dump();
matches1.Dump();
```

This gives the following correct output (i.e. two matches in first string and only one match in second):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

on nregex.com, I got the following to work with all examples:

```
\"([^"])*(##xyz##)([^"])*\"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to parse attributes in xml then you cannot just find ##xyz## between quotes.  For instance:

```
<a i="2"/> ##xyz## <a i="##xyz##"/>
```

Your regex will match:

```
"/> ##xyz## <a i="
```

You can try something like:

```
\"[^\"<>]*(##xyz##)[^\"<>]*\"
```

Note I used \" which you don't need to, but it works.